# Javascript: Adding elements of multiple integer and integer ranges into an array without also adding the ranges themselves

Tags: javascript, html

**GOAL**: **add all elements from an array of integers and arrays**, each child array is a set of 2 integers denoting a start and end of a range.

**HTML** invocation:

```
    <div class="block" onclick="test([33,88,[1,5],[8,13],[22,25]]);">click</div>
    <div id="paper"></div>
```

I have the following **JavaScript**:

```
    <script>
    function test(clickArray) {
    let theArray = [];
        for (i = 0; i < clickArray.length; i++) {
            theArray.push(clickArray[i]);
            if (clickArray[i].length > 1) {
                range(clickArray[i][0], clickArray[i][1], theArray);
            }
        }
    writeArray(theArray);
    }
    
    function writeArray(anArray) {
    let pencilArray = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < anArray.length; i++) {
            pencilArray.push();
        }
            document.getElementById("paper").innerHTML = pencilArray.join("<br>");
    }
    
    function range(start, end, rangeArray) {
        for (let i = start; i <= end; i++) {
            rangeArray.push(i);
        }
        return rangeArray;
    }
    </script>
```

When I invoke the onclick JavaScript the **output** is:

```
33
88
1,5
1
2
3
4
5
8,13
8
9
10
11
12
13
22,25
22
23
24
25
```

**Both** the **range passed** and the **elements constructed by the range() function** are **added to the final array**, but **I just want the elements**, not the ranges, so output should be:

```
33
88
1
2
3
4
5
8
9
10
11
12
13
22
23
24
25
```

Comment: remove `theArray.push(clickArray[i]);`

Comment: @Jamiec, that works beautifully, thanks. However, I also want to be able to add single integers along with the ranges. So if I just apply the range() function to all clickArray elements only actual ranges get returned... I would have to wrap each individual integer non-range as a range; [33,33]. Is there a way to handle both cases elegantly?

Comment: @Broadsworde So you also want to pass numbers directly? check my answer

Comment: @RameshReddy, understood, but single integers are not returned from the range() function, so are missing from the final array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how you can handle numbers along with ranges.

```js
const test = (arr) => {
  const allNumbers = arr.reduce((acc, el) => {
    if (Array.isArray(el)) {
      const [start, end] = el;
      for (let i = start; i <= end; i++) {
        acc.push(i)
      }
    } else if (!Number.isNaN(el)) {
      acc.push(el)
    }
    return acc
  }, [])

  document.getElementById('paper').innerHTML = allNumbers.join('<br />');
}
```

```html
<div class="block" onclick="test([[1,5],[8,13],[22,25], 99]);">click</div>
<div id="paper"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks Ramesh, that totally works. As you can see my approach to javascript is pretty old-school, do you have any recommended online reading to get me up to speed on the newer better ways?!

Comment: @Broadsworde You can check [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide) anytime you have a doubt with prototype methods of an array, string etc.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a simple [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) operation:

```js
const test = (array) => array.reduce((a, [s, e]) => {
  while(s <= e) a.push(s++);
  return a;
}, []);

const result = test([[1,5],[8,13],[22,25]]);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

It is generally [not a good idea](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events) to use inline event handlers. Here's a snippet using [Event Delegation](https://javascript.info/event-delegation), and a one line [reducer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) (`test`) to create the ranges from a string containing range values (two values or a single range)

```js
document.addEventListener(`click`, handle);

// reducer here
const test = array => array.reduce( (acc, [s, e]) => 
  acc.concat( [...Array(e + 1 - s)].map( (v, i) => i + s) ), [] );

function handle(evt) {
  if (evt.target.dataset.ranges) {
    // make sure a range contains two values. This allows single numbers
    const createRawRange = val => val.length < 2 ? [val, val] : val;
    // create ranges array from dataset, convert strings to Number
    const ranges = evt.target.dataset.ranges.split(";")
      .reduce( (acc, val) => 
        [...acc, createRawRange(val.split(`,`)).map(Number)], [] );
    // apply reducer (test) and print
    document.querySelector(`pre`).textContent = JSON.stringify(test(ranges));
  }
}
```

```html
Add ranges <button data-ranges="88;1,5;8,13;22,25;33;43,47">
<!--                            ^ single value --> 
  88; 1-5; 8-13; 22-25; 33; 43-47
</button>
<pre></pre>
```

Comment: Thanks KooiInc, I take your point, and will have a go with this approach.